# form attached JS attributes

Tags: 7, forms, javascript

I'm trying to convert this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="/Scripts/submenu/main" src="/Scripts/require.js"></script>
```

into something like this:

```
$form['#attached']['js'] = array(
        libraries_get_path('lib').'/Scripts/require.js' => array(
            '#attributes' => array('data-main' => 'main'),
        ),
);
```

but I can't seem to find the way to add an attribute :(
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

From what I remember, `drupal_add_js`, which ultimately is called, doesn't support attributes in the script element. You can use `drupal_add_html_head` to add js with other attributes; the [docs page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7) has some examples on how to do this.

Comment: that's what I end up using :(